# When using jenkins in openshift, how to make sure that maven is invoked in the correct directory?

Tags: jenkins, openshift, jenkins-pipeline

Im running a jenkins-ephemeral pod in my openshift project. This is my Jenkinsfile.

```
pipeline{
    agent {
        label 'maven'
    }
    stages{
        stage('Checkout from GitLab'){
            steps{
                echo "GitLab Check out..."
                git branch: "<git-branch-here>",
                credentialsId: "<gitlab-credentials-here>",
                url: "git@gitlab.hostname.blah:projects/spring-boot-helloworld.git"
            }
        }
        stage('Invoking mvn commands'){
            steps{

                sh "mvn clean install package"
            }
        }
        stage('Create the Image Builder'){
            when{
                expression{
                    openshift.withCluster(){
                        return !openshift.selector("bc", "new-pipeline").exists()
                    }
                }
            }
            steps{
                script{
                    openshift.withCluster(){
                        openshift.withProject(){
                            echo "Creating a new build."
                            def created = openshift.newBuild("--name=new-pipeline", "--image-stream=springboot-maven3", "--binary")

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is...

```
[start-build:buildconfig/new-pipeline] [ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/opt/app-root/src). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
[start-build:buildconfig/new-pipeline] [ERROR]
[start-build:buildconfig/new-pipeline] [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[start-build:buildconfig/new-pipeline] [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[start-build:buildconfig/new-pipeline] [ERROR]
[start-build:buildconfig/new-pipeline] [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[start-build:buildconfig/new-pipeline] [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
[start-build:buildconfig/new-pipeline] error: build error: non-zero (13) exit code from codecentric/springboot-maven3-centos@sha256:91ecee201c42cfde8616dfe7b5c77c4f6100f95f50c6e8ffe16a78c99dde59bf
[start-build:buildconfig/new-pipeline] 
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Create DEV)
Stage 'Create DEV' skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: Error running start-build on at least one item: [buildconfig/new-pipeline];
{reference={}, err=Uploading file "target/hello-world-service-1.0.0.jar" as binary input for the build ...
error: the build pipelineproject/new-pipeline-1 status is "Failed", verb=start-build, cmd=oc --server=https://172.30.0.1:443 --certificate-authority=/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt --namespace=pipelineproject --token=XXXXX start-build buildconfig/new-pipeline --from-file=./target/hello-world-service-1.0.0.jar --wait --follow -o=name , out=build/new-pipeline-1
Receiving source from STDIN as file hello-world-service-1.0.0.jar
---> Restore build artifacts
---> Installing application source
---> Building Spring Boot application from source
--> # MVN_ARGS =
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.095 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-11-06T04:19:02+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/360M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/opt/app-root/src). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
error: build error: non-zero (13) exit code from codecentric/springboot-maven3-centos@sha256:91ecee201c42cfde8616dfe7b5c77c4f6100f95f50c6e8ffe16a78c99dde59bf, status=1}
```

I went inside the jenkins pod via: oc rsh jenkins-1-vwt2g

And tried to look for the /opt/app-root/src directory

```
sh-4.2$ pwd
/opt
sh-4.2$ cd app-root
sh: cd: app-root: No such file or directory
```

I also looked for the hello-world-service-1.0.0.jar

```
sh-4.2$ cd /
sh-4.2$ find . -name hello*.jar
```

But I didnt find any.

I looked for the directory where the git source is downloaded.

```
sh-4.2$ pwd
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/pipelineproject/jobs/pipelineproject-hello-world-pipeline-ver2/workspace
sh-4.2$ ls -al
total 36
drwxr-sr-x. 4 default 1000260000   191 Nov  6 02:43 .
drwxr-sr-x. 7 default 1000260000   191 Nov  6 04:12 ..
drwxr-sr-x. 8 default 1000260000   162 Nov  6 02:43 .git
-rw-r--r--. 1 default 1000260000   381 Nov  6 02:43 hello-world-pipeline-ver2.yaml
-rw-r--r--. 1 default 1000260000  5934 Nov  6 02:43 Jenkinsfile
-rw-r--r--. 1 default 1000260000 10635 Nov  6 02:43 pom.xml
drwxr-sr-x. 3 default 1000260000    18 Nov  6 02:43 src
```

The error message mentioned /opt/app-root/src, but the source folder where the git source was downloaded to is /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/pipelineproject/jobs/pipelineproject-hello-world-pipeline-ver2/workspace

How do I reconcile this in my jenkins pipeline inside openshift so when I execute the startBuild it knows where the actual jar file is (I don't even know where maven generated the jar file -- after that mvn clean install package command ).

By the way, in mvn command specifically the install command, this is the related log

```
[INFO] Installing /tmp/workspace/pipelineproject/pipelineproject-hello-world-pipeline-ver2/target/hello-world-service-1.0.0.jar to /home/jenkins/.m2/repository/blah/blah/blah/spring-boot/hello-world-service/1.0.0/hello-world-service-1.0.0.jar
```

I have a /home directory but it doesn't contain anything (i.e. no jenkins/... directory).

```
openshift v3.9.43
kubernetes v1.9.1+a0ce1bc657
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this work by using a different image stream (i.e. I replaced the springboot-maven3 image with the redhat openjdk image). At the same time, the different directories that I was looking for are not found inside the jenkins pod, but instead it is in the Maven slave pod that is provided by the Jenkins pod by default.